# How do I get data from another table?

Tags: sql, join

I have a database with two tables, table 'product' and table 'factory'.
The table `product` has a column called `factory_id` and the table `factory` has both `factory_id` and 'factory_name'.

I have a bootstrap table which outputs all the fields the `product` table has, but how do I get the `factory_name` in there? I know I have to join tables but I don't really know how.

Comment: Can you show an example query you wrote?

Comment: A great place to start is the manual for what ever DB system you are using. Here's the mysql one, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html. The PHP tag seems irrelevant since this is just a SQL question.

Comment: Did you look up some examples of `JOIN` syntax in SQL?  "How do I use `JOIN`?" can essentially be answered by just looking at the documentation.  What have you tried and how is it not working?

Comment: How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How to join: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT product.*, factory.factory_name
FROM product
LEFT JOIN factory ON product.factory_id = factory.factory_id;
```

This should work, but next time try including some code you tried yourself when you ask a question.